# Startup Crash iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash-reports

I'm making an application, which is using GCM, background task and keychain to save user's information. I released a version using my developments certification by adding our device UDID to apple developer account. But after few days, I got feedback from users that, there is crash whenever startup. I review code but cannot find these bug. I got this logs:

```
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone securityd[9174] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone securityd[9174] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone amfid[10315] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone securityd[9174] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone securityd[9174] <Error>:  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone amfid[10315] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf Revocation1]
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone amfid[10315] <Notice>: developer cert trust result = 5
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone amfid[10315] <Error>: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/446DE89C-A427-4A51-AEA9-7AC86DFD088A/App.app/App not valid: 0xe8008018: The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.xxxxx.App[0xb005][10966]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone assertiond[9148] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 10966: (os/kern) failure (5)
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone SpringBoard[9139] <Warning>: Unable to register for exec notifications: No such process
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone SpringBoard[9139] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 10966: (os/kern) failure (5)
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone SpringBoard[9139] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x1425836d0; com.xxxx.App; pid: 10966>
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone SpringBoard[9139] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.xxxxx.App[0xb005]' exited abnormally via signal.
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone SpringBoard[9139] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone SpringBoard[9139] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone SpringBoard[9139] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone SpringBoard[9139] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone SpringBoard[9139] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone SpringBoard[9139] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Nov 23 16:34:51 iPhone SpringBoard[9139] <Warning>: Application '(null)' exited for an unknown reason.
```

Please help me with this. Thank you all. I often revoke and create new certificates and provisioning profile and use to programme with it. Is it fine?

Comment: Got any error when compiling? As always, try cleaning the project: `cmd`+`shift`+`clean`, that sometimes helps already. Also `The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.` means something is not right with your signing identity, probably not the reason for the crash but you should try to fix that as well.

Comment: I didn't get error when compiling, I have thought about the identity was invalid. But some of device currently still running, but others crashed and cannot launch app again. I don't know how to find what error right here.

Comment: Try this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20193

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H Thanks for your respond. I replaced the certification from development to distribution, so that my app can run fine. I don't know why. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know you have a workaround but I prefer to explain why this happens

You need an entitlement file on your project and enable the APNS with development or distribution. [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingLocalAndPushNotifications.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dic>
```

Maybe your file is like that but pointing to distribution, so using development will cause it to crash

Hope it's helps

Answer (score 0):

Although the stack is not very clear, its narrowing down your crash to few things.

1. Your certificates doesn't seem to be valid - Please go to Keychain Access and check if you have a valid certificate and the Keypair is attached to it.
2. Your Provisioning profile became invalid. Go to developer.apple.com and make sure your provisioning profile you used are valid.
3. Facebook application permissions are revoked for some reason. Please check your Facebook application and make sure everything is alright.